# NUXT system, global, application store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I need to store and access certain system information.

Kind of singleton but stored in memory.

Imagine that I have User-Logged counter, an user is viewing a page with x users logged in, then a 2nd user logs in, so the page should refresh to x + 1 in every user.

I was thinking in the Vue Reactivity, but first I need to store user quantity in general variable.

**EDIT:**

The thing is I need the global variable, not how to render. Please Focus on the title

**EDIT2:**

Forget the way I render, Imagine I have an API key used by all users, but I can't store it in process.env or nuxtConfig because this API changes frecuently. Where and how can I store it to get reachable from any user and then, if it changes, all user will access the new API next time they need it.

Comment: You'd need something like Websockets to broadcast the change.

Comment: @ceejayoz I was thinking in Reacivity vue components like vue.observe.

Comment: You'd have to react to *something*, though.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.socket.io for example. Looks like you need a common functionality for chat

Comment: The thing is I need the global variable, not how to render. Please Focus on the title

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Websockets. This functionality has to be implemented in your backend web service.
Then in your front-end, listen to every user login to reload the page for all users.